How can I remove the word limit in product descriptions in Wordpress?
I have an online store for my Wordpress site using Woocommerce. I am using a product excerpt block but it keeps truncating my text halfway through the description. I can't get it to show the rest of the text.
This is the product page: https://www.angosta.co/producto/prohibido-tocarse/
I've tried adding code snippets I've found online but nothing is working. For example,
function force_full_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    // Check if we are on a single product page
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        // Return the full content instead of the excerpt
        return apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
    }
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'force_full_excerpt', 10, 1 );


Try this custom solution:
function custom_product_description() {
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt' );
    return get_the_excerpt();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'custom_product_description' );

